# Не могу отправить кроссдоменный AJAX запрос из своей формы. Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: ajax, http, post, запрос

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Данные формы</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="LoginForm" action="https://prostozaim.com.ua/login">
   <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="KBJFK518pv_T9XaOTA8RbfVDxjXQkhfFIr3GFEmpt9d-ZNunk4rtDGYZ4GGWIILQiyKRlyZs548GLLe5H8c4rtNo9F9QUG1yTwZs-5UfZxg1">
   <p><input name="loginEmail" id="LoginEmail"> <input type="password" name="LoginPassword" id="LoginPassword"></p>
  </form>
  <p><input type="submit" id="qw"></p>
  <div id="result"><div>
  <script>
   qw.onclick=function(){
   var formdate = new FormData(document.forms.LoginForm);
   var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.withCredentials = true;
   xhr.open("POST", "https://prostozaim.com.ua/login", true);
   xhr.send(formdate);
   alert(xhr.responseText);};
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Нужно с помощью `Ajax post` запроса авторизоваться по заданному *URL* из своей формы.

Скажите, что не так? Что лишнее? Или как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert(xhr.responseText);` работать не будет, так как вы не дожидаясь ответа, сразу пытаетесь его вывести. Вам нужно написать обработчик события ответа сервера. А затем делать `alert`

```
var formdate = new FormData(document.forms.LoginForm);
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open("POST", "https://prostozaim.com.ua/login", true);
xhr.send(formdate);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

   if (xhr.status != 200) {
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
   } else {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
   }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отлично

Comment: @sveimk Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как правильный.